# Hamiltonian Graph Problem

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I've been going about the proof of the Snark Graph's 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)) 
non-Hamiltonicity. I understand that a snark is connected, bridgeless (
removing any edge does not make the graph unconnected), cubic (
$\forall\ v \in V(G), \deg(v) = 3),$ and a chromatic index of 4 ($\chi^\prime(G) = 4$).

I am having some issues
synthesizing these properties to show there is at least two vertices without
a Hamiltonian path in between them. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you mean to say that there is no hamiltonian path for ANY pair of vertices

Comment: $K_4$ is connected, bridgeless, cubic, and the vertices need 4 colors, but it has a Hamiltonian path, indeed, a Hamiltonian circuit, so there must be more to this question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Doesn't "chromatic *index*" usually refer to edge colorings?

Comment: @bof, you might be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume a snark has a Hamiltonian cycle. A snark has an even number of vertices (Handshaking lemma) so we can color the edges of the cycle red and blue. The edges that are not part of the cycle form a perfect matching. Color the edges of the perfect matching green. We have a 3-edge coloring of a snark, a contradiction.

Comment: Excellent: short and to the point! +1